# Дамп кеша сделанного PHP OPcache

Tags: php, ram

Каким образом можно сделать дамп закешированых PHP OPcache скриптов?

Модель памяти используется `mmap`.

Comment: А что вы хотите видеть в этом дампе?

Comment: @Naumov ОпКоды скриптов.Проще говоря результат кеширования скрипта.

Comment: А зачем?.......

Comment: @Naumov В целях самообучения:)

Comment: Ну перекомпелирйте опкэшь и пхп через опцию -d и после через gdb запускай и далее по точкам остановки делай дамп